# Auto notification on adding new document in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, notifications

I had created a workflow for auto notification in SharePoint designer.

It was working absolutely fine.

Now I am not receiving any notification on adding new document.

I checked the workflow and it is absolutely fine. Not sure why I am not receiving the emails.

Comment: Is workflow running on adding new documents? What is its status completed or suspended? Is there any chance someone else removed the association of workflow from library?

Comment: If you manually run the workflow does it send the email?

Comment: No. neither it is. i have re checked if some one has modified the workflow but there is no change at all.